# Rails: monkey-patching ActiveRecord::Base vs creating a Module

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, inheritance, activerecord, callback

I am reading through [The Rails 4 way](https://leanpub.com/tr4w) (by Obie Fernandez), a well-known book about Rails, and from what I've read so far, I can highly recommend it.

However, there is an example section *9.2.7.1: Multiple Callback Methods in One Class* that confuses me:

Bear with me, to make the problem clear for everyone, I have replicated the steps the book describes in this question.

---

The section talks about Active Record callbacks (`before_create`, `before_update` and so on), and that it is possible to create a class that handles multiple callbacks for you. The listed code is as follows:

```
class Auditor
   def initialize(audit_log)
      @audit_log = audit_log
   end

   def after_create(model)
      @audit_log.created(model.inspect)
   end

   def after_update(model)
      @audit_log.updated(model.inspect)
   end

   def after_destroy(model)
      @audit_log.destroyed(model.inspect)
   end
end
```

The book says then that *to add this audit logging to an Active Record class, you would do the following*:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
   after_create Auditor.new(DEFAULT_AUDIT_LOG)
   after_update Auditor.new(DEFAULT_AUDIT_LOG)
   after_destroy Auditor.new(DEFAULT_AUDIT_LOG)
   ...
end
```

The book then notes that *this code is very ugly, having to add three Auditors on three lines*, and that it not DRY. It then goes ahead and tells us that to solve this problem, we should monkey-patch an `acts_as_audited` method into the `Active Record::Base` object, as follows:

(the book suggests putting this file in `/lib/core_ext/active_record_base.rb`)

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
   def self.acts_as_audited(audit_log=DEFAULT_AUDIT_LOG)
      auditor = Auditor.new(audit_log)
      after_create auditor
      after_update auditor
      after_destroy auditor
   end
end
```

which enables you to write the Account Model class as follows:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
   acts_as_audited
   ...
end
```

---

Before reading the book, I have already made something similar that adds functionality to multiple Active Record models. The technique I used was to create a Module. To stay with the example, what I have done was similar to:

(I would put this file inside `/app/models/auditable.rb`)

```
module Auditable
   def self.included(base)
      @audit_log = base.audit_log || DEFAULT_AUDIT_LOG #The base class can override it if wanted, by specifying a self.audit_log before including this module
      base.after_create audit_after_create
      base.after_update audit_after_update
      base.after_destroy audit_after_destroy
   end

   def audit_after_create
      @audit_log.created(self.inspect)
   end

   def audit_after_update
      @audit_log.updated(self.inspect)
   end

   def audit_after_destroy
      @audit_log.destroyed(self.inspect)
   end
end
```

Note that this file both replaces the `Auditor` and the monkey-patched `ActiveRecord::Base` method. The `Account` class would then look like:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
   include Auditable
   ...
end
```

---

Now you've read both the way the book does it, and the way I would have done it in the past. My question: **Which version is more sustainable in the long-term?** I realize that this is a slightly opinionated question, just like everything about Rails, but to keep it answerable, I basically want to know:

- Why would you want to monkey-patch `ActiveRecord::Base` directly, over creating and including a `Module`?

Comment: I believe the only reason is that `acts_as_audited` speaks for itself. That is more or less comprehensible that `include Auditable`.

Comment: Although an opinionated question, it is a very good one. And i agree with @mudasobwa, one of the reasons is that is it more readable. But, as all monkey-patches, it becomes susceptible to another gem to harm your code by doing the same thing, defining the same methods, etc.

Comment: Module is definitely a more clear solution. Don't use magic if you don't need it. `acts_as_...` is more like Rails 1 way to me, when all the Ruby monkey-patching capabilities were new and tempting. Rails 4 is mature and adult, it doesn't need fancy stuff, it just makes the job done.

Comment: @mudasobwa: Say you are a new developer that is fresh on the project, and something goes wrong with the auditor. Would you easily be able to find where acts_as_audited is defined? Because it is a monkey-patch, In such a situation I would be inclined to presume that it's a built-in Rails function I did not know about.

Comment: `Auditable` module seems like right way - as you have a choice to make select models to be auditable - by monkey patching the `ActiveRecord:::Base`, we lose that choice.  Personally, I have come to realize that trickery in code will only make code difficult to understand and not to mention, makes life of new developers frustrating

Comment: I don't think `acts_as_audited` speaks or even clarifies anything. If I was new dev on the project wanting to change it's behavior, I would assume its a gem and only then searched for definition in codebase. On the other side `include Auditable` would tell me there is a module called `Auditable` which does something that I can check if I peek at it. Long story short(er) I also prefer module approach.

Answer (score 2):

I would go for the module for a few reasons.

Its obvious; that is to say, I can quickly find the code that defines this behavior. In `acts_as_*` I don't know if its from some gem, library code, or defined within this class. There could be implications about it being overridden or piggy-backed in the call-stack.

Its portable. It uses method calls that are commonly defined in libraries that define callbacks. You could conceivably distribute and use this library in non-active-record objects.

It avoids the addition of *unnecessary* code on the static level. I'm a fan of having **less** code to manage (less code to break). I like using Ruby's niceties without doing to much to force it to be "nicer" than it already it is.

In a monkey-patch setting you are tying the code to a class or module that could go away and there are scenarios where it would fail silently until your class can't call `acts_as_*`.

One downfall of the portability argument is the testing argument. In which case I would say you can write your code to protect *against* portability, or fail early with smart warnings about what will and won't work when used portably.